# Pieces of plastic that came with my bike, what are these?

Tags: mountain-bike, equipment

I've looked into my 6 years old Mountain Bike manual and in the bag with it and all the warranties I found these 5 pieces of plastic, what are they made for?
[image: 5 pieces of plastic]
[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Those looks like spacers used to protect the bike during shipping.

Comment: Nice, thoughtfully composed (informative) photos.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image: Labeled Parts]

These are cable guide parts.  From the looks of it, you have:

1. 2 Housing shims, used to secure hydraulic lines or brake housing in the braze-ons of the frame, or for securing the housing at the point it enters the frame in the case of internal housing.
2. 1 Headset adjustment bolt button, used to keep water out of the bolt in the center of your headset cap, or to hide the bolt.
3. 2 Hydraulic line clips, used to secure hydraulic lines or cable housing on a particular type of housing guide on the outside of a frame or the back of a suspension fork.

Many frames come with extras of these parts, so it may be that you have no need for them at this time.  Or you might, if the LBS did a poor job of assembly. No way for us to know without seeing your bike.

Comment: the bike is perfectly working without them, thank you

Comment: @MassimoPesavento yet you better put that brake housing shims and clips to secure them. They are tend to get ruined if they are too free.

Comment: @Alexander Would you please post a picture or two showing exactly where they should be put? Thanks
I can upload a pic of my bike if you want

Comment: Older bikes had a 'braze on's that cable housing was coming into. Now on your bike you can find some "preparing for braze on", so the clips going there. You can see one at the photo's right bottom angle. http://www.bikerumor.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/TRP-HyWire-di2-integrated-hydraulic-disc-road-brakes01.jpg You can also see the headset adjustment bolt with no button (right top side of the bike).